# Debugging background tasks

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, live-tile

**It seems to me, that my background task is not working / triggering. Is there any way i can debug them, or test it with an integration test.**

This is an example background task:

```
public sealed class MyBackgroundTask : IBackgroundTask
{
 private ITileService _tileService;

 //Tried a parameter-less constructor in case IoC doesn't work
 public MyBackgroundTask() : this(new TileService)  {}

 public MyBackgroundTask(ITileService tileService)
 {
     _tileService = tileservice;
 }

        public async void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("MyBackgroundTask is running " + taskInstance.Task.Name );
            taskInstance.Canceled += TaskInstanceOnCanceled;
            if (!_cancelRequest && SomeOtherCondition)
            {
                var deferral = taskInstance.GetDeferral(); 
                await _tileService.UpdateLiveTile(null);
                deferral.Complete();
            }
        }
}
```

Registration of background task : 
(This code runs, checked with debugger)

```
var backgroundTaskBuilder = new BackgroundTaskBuilder
                                                {
                                                    TaskEntryPoint =
                                                        "MyNamespace.MyBackgroundTask",
                                                    Name = "MyBackgroundTask"
                                                };

                backgroundTaskBuilder.SetTrigger(new MaintenanceTrigger(15, false));
                backgroundTaskBuilder.AddCondition(new SystemCondition(SystemConditionType.InternetAvailable));
                backgroundTaskBuilder.Register();
```

In the app manifest I have defined a new `BackgroundTask` with a `System Event` and the following entry point: `MyNamespace.MyBackgroundTask`

Note:
The background task is in a different assembly as the app (Back-end / front-end separation)

Comment: Relevant docs: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj542415.aspx